# tough question about multiple improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0,\infty)^2 \to \mathbb{R}$

$$
   f(x,y) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0 & : x =0\\\
       \arctan( \frac{y}{x}) & :0 \leq \arctan( \frac{y}{x}) \leq \frac{\pi}{4}\\
-\arctan(\frac{y}{x})+ \frac{\pi}{4} &: \frac{\pi}{4} \leq \arctan( \frac{y}{x}) \leq \frac{\pi}{2}
     \end{array}
   \right.
  $$

I want to argue that $$\lim_{ \alpha \to \infty} \int_{B(0, \alpha) } f$$

exists but, $\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} \int_{[0,\alpha] \times [0, \alpha]} f $ does not exists. How can I show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In polar coordinates, for every $\alpha>0$, we have
$$\eqalign{
\int_{B(0,\alpha)}f&=\int_0^\alpha\left(\int_0^{\pi/4}\theta d\theta+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}(\tfrac{\pi}{4}-\theta)d\theta\right)rdr\cr
&=\int_0^\alpha\left(\int_0^{\pi/4}\theta d\theta-\int_0^{{\pi/4}}\theta d\theta\right)rdr=0
}
$$
Thus, $\lim\limits_{\alpha\to\infty}\int_{B(0,\alpha)}f=0$. On the other hand

$$\eqalign{
\int_{[0,\alpha]^2}f&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\theta\left(\int_0^{\alpha/\cos\theta}rdr\right)d\theta
+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}(\tfrac{\pi}{4}-\theta)\left(\int_0^{\alpha/\sin\theta}rdr\right)d\theta\cr
&=\alpha^2\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\theta}{2\cos^2\theta}d\theta
+\alpha^2\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac{ \tfrac{\pi}{4}-\theta }{2\sin^2\theta}d\theta\cr
&=\alpha^2\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\theta}{\cos2\theta+1}d\theta
-\alpha^2\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\frac{ \theta-\tfrac{\pi}{4} }{\cos2\theta-1}d\theta\cr
&=\alpha^2\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\theta}{\cos2\theta+1}d\theta
-\alpha^2\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{ \theta}{-\sin2\theta-1}d\theta\cr
&=\alpha^2\int_0^{\pi/4}\left(\frac{1}{\cos2\theta+1}+\frac{1}{\sin2\theta+1}\right)\theta d\theta\cr
&\geq\alpha^2\frac{\pi}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}\alpha^2
}
$$
So. $\lim\limits_{\alpha\to\infty}\int_{[0,\alpha]^2}f=+\infty$.

Comment: thank you! one question: Why in the second part the limits of integration with respect to $r$ are $\alpha / \cos \theta $  and $\alpha / \sin \theta $ ?

Comment: Note that $[0,\alpha]^2$ is a square, for $\theta\leq\pi/4$, $r$ varies from $0$ to the $r_{max}(\theta)$: length of the hypotenuse of the right triangle, with one side equal to $\alpha$ and the angle between this side and   the hypotenuse being $\theta$ so $\cos\theta=\frac{\alpha}{r_{max}(\theta)}$ or $r_{max}(\theta)=\frac{\alpha}{cos(\theta)}$. A similar, argument works when $\theta>\pi/4$ with the upper side of the square.

Comment: I cannot read this. sorry :s

Comment: I see now ! Why does the last inequality follows? is it because $ \int_A f \geq \inf_A f \times length(A) $ ?

Comment: yes, sure, clearly $1+\cos 2\theta\leq 2$ so $1/(1+\cos2\theta)\geq1/2$, and similarly for the second inequality.